# Multiple sticky elements disappear in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, sticky

In Firefox 89.0 multiple sticky elements disappears without a reason.

Here is an example (usage of position: sticky):

```
<table>
<tr style="position: sticky; top: 0px; height: 30px;"></tr>
<tr style="position: sticky; top: 30px; height: 30px;"></tr>
<tr style="position: sticky; top: 60px; height: 30px;"></tr>
<tr style="position: sticky; top: 90px; height: 30px;"></tr>
...
</table>
https://jsfiddle.net/mcdhnzgy/11/
```

Just scroll down and hover wild over sticky elements.

Are there some CSS styles or JavaScript missing, or is this just a weird browser bug?
In Chrome everything seems fine.

**Additional note**: Solution should work with table markup and should work with multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an issue with the table in firefox. I face this issue when i scroll down and hover on the sticky element and then move my mouse out of the result box. You can fix this issue by adding this style:
[image]

```
table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arminya/t7avu5w1/1/

Comment: Thank you for discovering that it is table bug. Unfortunately I can't use your fix. With one column it would work fine but with more columns a width for each cell must be then applied (and calculated). I really want to use a table and not flex or grid for many reasons (semantic, auto width by table logic, ...).

Comment: Sry for not saying that it should work for multiple columns and as a table. I thought it would be simpler for reproducing the bug when using only one column. I updated the question.